# How to launch multiple AutoHotkey scripts at once?

Tags: windows, autohotkey

Launching multiple scripts would mainly be beneficial to restore the running scripts after an AutoHotkey update as all process must be killed prior to the installation. Currently I restart my computer instead.

Personally I store the shortcuts in the Windows startup folder for scripts I want to be running at all times so a solution for both the .ahk files and Windows shortcuts is optimal.

Answer (score 0):

A "quick and dirty" solution would be to run a PowerShell script on startup and/or logon that would keep watch on AutoHotKey script processes and if they are ever killed, launch the scripts again. You could add a delay between when the script notices that there are no processes running, and when it launches them again to give AHK the time to update.

Needs like these are often solved by "quick and dirty" scripts like the one I suggested since there's no other easy way (or built-in way) to meet them.